# Why is the postulate $1$ not equal to $0$ not superfluous?

Tags: geometry, axioms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explanation for why $1\neq 0$ is explicitly mentioned in Chapter 1 of Spivak's Calculus for properties of numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164811/explanation-for-why-1-neq-0-is-explicitly-mentioned-in-chapter-1-of-spivaks-c)

I am self-studying the wonderful book, *Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint*.

In chapter 1, problem 18 it says: *Postulate M-6 (which says `1 not equal to 0`) may seem superfluous. Is it? Can it be proved, on the basis of the other postulates, that there is any number at all other than 0?*

The "other postulates" include the commutativity, associativity, identity, and distributive laws for addition and multiplication.

I don't see how to show that without the postulate `1 not equal to 0` it cannot be shown that there is any number other than 0. Would you help please?

Answer (score 21):

Show that the set $\{0\}$ with the usual addition and multiplication satisfies all of your postulates except M-6. This gives a model of the other postulates in which M-6 is false, which shows that it’s independent of the others.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming what I expect is there, the set consisting of just a number $0$ satisfies all axioms, with operations $0+0=0$ and $0 \cdot 0 = 0.$ The usual role of the symbol $1$ is that $1 \cdot x = x,$ but that is taken care of here, with $1=0,$ by $0 \cdot 0 = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

The axioms are the [Field axioms.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29) As a hint, consider the analogous problem of showing that the Field axioms do not imply that $\:1 + 1 \ne 0.\:$ If the implication held true then $1 + 1 \ne 0\:$ would be true in every field. To refute the implication it suffices to find a counterexample: a field with $1 + 1= 0.$ But everyone knows such a field, namely Parity Arithmetic, i.e. the integers modulo $2$, which one easily checks satisfies all the Field axioms, using the operation tables below, e.g. the commutative laws hold because the operation tables are symmetric.

$$\begin{array}{rcl} 
\rm Parity\ Arithmetic & &\rm\!\!\! modulo\ 2 \\
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
+ & \bf\text{even} &\rm\bf odd\\\hline
\bf\text{even} & \text{even} & \text{odd}\\\hline
\rm\bf odd & \text{odd} &\rm even\\\hline
\end{array} \!\!\!\!\!\!\!& \iff &\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
+ & \bf 0  & \bf 1\\\hline
\bf 0 & 0 & 1\\\hline
\bf 1 & 1 & 0\\\hline
\end{array} \\
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
\times  & \bf\text{even} &\rm odd\\\hline
\bf\text{even} & \text{even} & \text{even}\\\hline
\rm\bf odd & \text{even} &\rm odd\\\hline
\end{array} \!\!\!\!\!\!\!& \iff &\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
\times  & \bf 0 & \bf 1 \\\hline
\bf 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
\bf 1 & 0 & 1\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Your problem is simpler since a counterexample has $\:1 = 0,\:$ hence $\rm\: x = 1\cdot x = 0\cdot x = 0,\:$ i.e. every element $= 0,\:$ so the structure has only the single element $0.\:$ The axiom for inverses is vacuously satisfied, since there are no nonzero elements to check for inverses. All other axioms are universal, i.e. identities such as $\rm\:\forall\, x,y\!:\ x+y = y + x,\:$ and they hold true for all elements simply because there is only a single value $\:0\:$ for the operations to take, so it can only evaluate to $\:0 = 0\:$ (vs. possibly $\rm\:1 = 0\:$ when verifying the two-element field above), see the operation tables below.

$$\rm\begin{array}{} Null\ Arithmetic\ (mod\ 1)\\
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
+     & \bf 0  \\\hline
\bf 0 &  0 \\\hline
\end{array}\quad 
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
*    &  \bf 0  \\\hline
\bf 0 &  0 \\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$